# Override main query for page template

Tags: pre-get-posts

I am using a page template to loop through posts there is already a main query, however, before the posts are displayed I only want the unexpired posts to display so I am using this code to add a final criteria;

```
<?php 

function live_posts_only( $query ) {

    $today = date('Ymd');
    $meta_query = array (
        'meta_key'      => 'sale_or_rent',
        'meta_value'    => 'sale',
        'meta_query' => array(
                'key'       => 'date_listing_expires',
                'compare'   => '>',
                'value'     => $today,
            ),
    );

    $query->set('meta_query',$meta_query);

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'live_posts_only' );

?>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 no-margin-left">
            Do stuff
</div>
```

However, when the page displays only one post is displayed and then the following notice is displayed;

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare live_posts_only()
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: More details needed to answer. but i guess live_posts_only() function is defined inside of loop.

Comment: @AbdulRehman I believe that is what is hapenning.

Comment: you cannot define a function inside of any loop. get that function out of loop or paste the complete code here so we will able to get some solution.

Comment: @AbdulRehman I put it in the function.php and it made all the posts disappear, but my custom 404 page worked fine and the all the correct posts were showing on that.